# Why do I need `$rootScope.$apply()` in my Angular Service?

Tags: angularjs

I have a pop-up modal service in my application called `Overlay`.  It simply flips some booleans on the `$rootScope` that cause 2 directives to show/hide appropriately.  Here is the function that is called when showing a new modal

```
 overlay.NewGears = {
        show: function(msg){
            _displayBackground();

            scope.message = msg;
            scope.feedback = null;
            scope.url = '/partials/Common/gears.html';

            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                $rootScope.modalVisible = true;
            });


        },
        hide: function(){
            _hideBackground();

            $rootScope.modalVisible = false;
        }
    };
```

As you can see I display the opaque background, then I set up a variable called `scope` which is later passed into my directive via DI. But then I noticed that my modal was not appearing when it should, and instead was appearing on the NEXT digest cycle after the `modalVisible` variable was set to true.  I then had to add the `$apply()` around the assignment to get it to work.  However, I thought this is only needed when we are outside the "Angular world", so why do I need this inside of my Angular Service?

Comment: When is `show` called?

Comment: Its called in my controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$apply` is necessary to tell angular that changes happened to the scope. Built-in directives and services like `ngClick` or `$http` do that internally. If you apply (sic!) changes to the scope and don't use the aforementioned built-in services, then you are responsible for calling `$apply` yourself.

So if `show` isn't called within an `ngClick`handler, e.g., then you need to call `$apply` yourself.