# call to controller function does not trigger $scope.$apply()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using a directive as a wrapper for custom form elements for a form builder tool. The directive is applied on each form element creating a basic template and an isolate scope (it is supposed to run within an ng-repeat for multiple form elements).

This directive "formElement" is applied together with a behavior directive "configurableElement" which bind a "click" event enables clicking allow configuring of each element in a different panel. When the click event is triggered on the "configurableElement" directive the latter triggers the basic directive's controller function called "edit" which in turns is supposed to access the basic application controller MainCtrl and trigger the "editElement" function which in turns set the "editedElement" property of the controller scope.

The problem is that although the controller ("MainCtrl") editElement function is called (i know because i see "triggered" in the console) the view does not gets the updated "editedElement" value. I do not want to set a timeout and call the $scope.$apply() function inside the controller to update the view. I just want to understand why this occurs.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.element = {label:"First Name", placeholder:"Type in your name"};
        $scope.editedElement = null;
        $scope.editElement = function(element) {
            console.log("triggered");
            $scope.editedElement = element;
        };      
   })
   .directive('formElement', function() {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/templates/elementView.html',
            scope: {
                element: '=formElementView',
                edit: '&configurableElement'
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                this.edit = function() {
                     $scope.edit({'element':$scope.element});
                };
            }
        };
   })
   .directive('textFormElement', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/templates/textElement.html',
        };
   })
   .directive('configurableElement', function(){
        return {
            require: '^formElementView',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes, formElementViewCtrl) {                   
                element.bind('click', function(){                       
                    formElementViewCtrl.edit();
                });
            }
        }
   });
```

the html is the following

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtlr">
        {{editedElement}}
        <div data-form-element-view="element" data-configurable-element="editElement(element)">
            <div data-text-form-element></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is Angular supposed to know that the scope has changed if no one calls `$scope.apply`?

Comment: don't calls to directive's controllers function trigger $apply automatically? i am asking because i see that if the function call happens in the directives's link function, $apply is auto triggered.

Comment: No and no. `scope.$apply` is called once after compilation or after the  application has started, if you will. So it may seem like `$apply` is "triggered", when in fact it's not, because it's called anyway. Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388180/why-do-i-need-rootscope-apply-in-my-angular-service/26388560#26388560) helps to understand the issue.

Comment: thanks i got it. thought $apply was wise to use only in the out-of-angular code.

Comment: the thing that still is unclear to me though. $scope.editedElement variable of the ng-controller was bound in the view. Doesn't angular automatically puts a watch to every $scope variable bound to the view? if i updated the property from calling the function to the controller, shouldn't this trigger $apply()?

Comment: `$apply` tells Angular that something has changed. Only then Angular calls all watchers. A watcher checks if the observed value is affected by the change.